# Is Delphi XE2 + Oxygene for Java a solid cross platform solution?

Tags: delphi

This question is really about Delphi XE2 capabilities, but since this cross platform stuff is new (especially the Oxygene Java), I'm curious if anyone has tried to target all 4 platforms from one Delphi/C++ code base using the XE2 toolchain.

I have been considering returning to the Delphi family since it seems that Embarcadero has some features that suggest that one could target Windows/MacOS/iOS/Android with a single code base. I'm assuming that for the Android part you would need the newly released Oxygene for Java 'Cooper' release from REMObjects.

So my question is if I purchase RAD Studio XE2 (which includes Prism) and add onto it Oxygene for Java, will I have a platform to actually target all these OSes with a single code base?  Will I have to use FireMonkey for the app, or can I still us VCL for cross-platform?  Are there any examples of *useful* applications that have been developed for iOS/Android yet with XE2? (The demos and examples I've seen seem pretty simplistic).

Comment: Whan in the Planck's name makes you think what this strugglings are more solid than real Java? Actually you better off direct such questions toward sales depts of respective vendors.

Comment: @user539484 Dean is trying to target multiple platforms from a single codebase.

Comment: Oh yes, really this should be a questions for the embarcadero sales department.  But I've been around long enough to know that these new widgits need to be actually used to develop something *useful* before you should jump onboard.  Embarcadero seems to be adding a lot in the XE/XE2 releases and I wanted some user experiences if available as to if this stuff is ready for prime time or not.

Comment: @DeanRoberson, thats quite subjective information you are requesting. IMO, Borkadero is never been ready for the prime time and becomes more and more esoteric while technology advances. In the case you want to stay with Pascal - there is FPC and its ultimate portability (granted what Lazarus widget are less portable)

Comment: I think it's too early for iOS development with FireMonkey. My most recent application failed crossing over to iOS because there was no Internet or database support. It did work for Windows/Mac, and I'm happy with that. Will be using Appcelerator Titanium for iOS/Android, so at least 2 code bases for now.

Comment: @Marcus I'm far from convinved that FMX is ready for prime time on any platform.

Comment: @Marcus 'No Internet or database support' - yeah, that's a show stopper for sure.  Oh well, I'm really mostly interested in the 64 bit and stability enhancements of the latest release.  I'll just consider the cross-platform stuff a work in progress and start developing some toy applications for now.

Comment: What do you mean of "applications for ioS/android with XE2?  There is ZERO in-the-box Android development capability shipped in XE2. You can use the regular Android SDK, plus a provided DataSnap "starter code" to talk to a data snap server, but that doesn't mean XE2 is intended as a Phone Developer Solution (yet).  Even the iOS stuff is really primitive.   It's early days yet, and XE3 and XE4 may become mobile-phone developer solutions, and that would be awesome.

Comment: I am still waiting for a Embarcadero RAD Studio version that we can code in Java language, with no modifications, just Java. Because Delphi GUI and VCL is just great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oxygene/Prism is a separate product from Delphi XE2 with a different, albeit similar, language. You can't use a single codebase shared between XE2 and Oxygene/Prism.

Embarcaderos plan's for iOS and Android will be based on their cross-platform Delphi compiler and the new FireMonkey libraries. The existing iOS support uses the FPC compiler but Embarcadero have stated that they are working on an ARM version of their Delphi compiler to replace that in future releases.

So, at the moment, of your 4 platforms, you can target Windows, MacOS and iOS with Delphi XE2/FireMonkey. But not Android, as of today.

With Prism/Oxygene you can target Windows, MacOS and Android (and Linux as it happens). Note however that there is nothing in the Prism/Oxygene akin to FireMonkey that allows you to write single source cross-platform GUI.

Comment: Thanks David.  Although it sounds like XE2 is not quite where I would want it for cross-platform, I may just jump in and get updated to XE2 to get on board.  I've been wanting an excuse to return to Delphi.

Comment: Not only is the Language itself somewhat different, the component set and the component set's capabilities (VCL for Delphi and FMX for Delphi, versus .NET libraries for Prism) are wildly different. So while you might be able to get around the language differences, you can't get around the platform-shift. In short, prism and Delphi are two different platforms that lack cross-platform compatibility even on Windows, let alone cross-platform capabilities on other OS.

Comment: @WarrenP It's even more subtle than that. The new Cooper product is based on Java and of course there is no WinForms there. So you can't even single source on Prism/Oxygene across all supported platforms. That's what I was trying to get across in my final paragraph.

Comment: Ah yes.  `Cooper` is cool, and yes, it rather does make a confusing panoply of options.    Frankly, if you just want cross-platform on all platforms that support `mono` already, you could just use Prism+mono, which works on Linux, Mac, and Windows.  I don't see much use for `Cooper` beyond a few dead or dying smartphone java platforms.

Comment: Now XE3 is waiting for Mobile Studio with the new ARM compiler for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Java is also meant for multiple platforms, so why try harder?

I've tried xe2 and I am disappointed. For Android and iOS you have to use PHP XE2, and for Delphi and OS-X you have to use Delphi XE2, so it's not an integrated technology. Embarcadero should release a True Java IDE Technology.

I am a Pascal Developer, but I sit my ass on the chair and Learned Java in a feel days, so why they make it so hard to try!?

Eclipse is great, but imagine a Java compatible Delphi IDE...

Comment: I am still waiting for a Embarcadero RAD Studio version that we can code in Java language, with no modifications, just Java. Because Delphi GUI and VCL is just great!